# Exception ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified occurs when connecting Heroku <-> Postgres (EC2)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, heroku

I've a Heroku app that is trying to connect to a Postgres DB on EC2. Here is the issue that I'm getting:

```
2011-05-30T23:07:48+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:66:in `establish_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

2011-05-30T23:07:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
```

I've followed the heroku instructions described [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#database_urls) to set up the database configurations on the heroku app. Here are some other things that might help:

1. I can connect to the postgresql db using a psgql admin on my computer (showcasing that the port forwarding and listening to hosts is set up correctly ..and no I'm not allowing ONLY my IP to enter - its wild carded so that all ips can connect)
2. The version of postgresql that i'm running on EC2 is 8.4 while Heroku normally uses 9.0 on their shared databases. Could this be the problem? (the reason I've not fixed this is because I don't know where to find pg_upgrade...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@amehta, no, 8.4 and 9.0 is not your problem. My naive guess is that your configuration is missing:

```
adapter: postgresql
```

The problem is entirely local inside of your Heroku setup. Try manually connecting from Heroku to EC2:

```
require 'postgres'
conn = PGconn.connect('amazone-host', 5432, '', '', 'dbname', 'username', 'pass')
puts conn.exec('SELECT version()')[0]
```

to see if you can further isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! You were dead on about the problem being entirely in the Heroku setup (and not the version,firewall etc). However, I've fully followed the instructions specified by Heroku and still cannot connect with the db on EC2. Is there anyway, I can look at the database configuration from Heroku console?

Comment: so i found a way to look up the database config file (puts File.read(Rails.configuration.database_configuration_file)) but it's kinda useless as I cannot even connect to the heroku console as the app is crashing because of a lack of db connectivity

Comment: does `heroku addons | grep POSTGRES` help?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that heroku overwrites the database.yml....so when you call ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:external_db)  there is no .yml definition for that db